# Processing S3 file in Active/Active regions in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-fargate

Hello Stackoverflow family,

I'm currently working on finding a solution for processing s3 file in active/active regions. The goal of this solution to have the file processed once to avoid duplication processing, And here's the scenario:

**East region:**

- S3 bucket
- Lambda function to run every T time  to check if S3 file is available and run a fargate task to pickup the file
- Fargate application to process S3 file
- Global dynamoDB to store processed data

**West region:**

- S3 bucket
- Lambda function to run every T time  to check if S3 file is available and run a fargate task to pickup the file
- Fargate application to process S3 file
- Global dynamoDB to store processed data

**Process:**

- Once on-prem service drops the file in S3(east or west), file will be replicated to the other region with T time.
- S3 file will have a tag that indicates a preferred region
- Once lambda function runs in both regions, it will trigger the fargate application to pickup the file and process it.
- Before fargate starts processing the file, it will tag it "In progress" to lock the file and prevents the other region from processing it.

**Problems:**

- Preferred region tagged in the S3 file might be down
- Both regions might tag the same file as theirs (due to replication T time)

**Question:**
The goal of this question to find a way to avoid deadlock situation, or duplicate processing for same file.

[image]

Comment: When you say "it will tag it "In progress" to lock the file", are you talking about tagging an object in Amazon S3, or in the DynamoDB database?

Comment: Investigate distributed lock solutions, for example the [DynamoDB Lock Client](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/).

Comment: I meant to add a tag to the S3 object as "locked by east" as example